# How to cross-compile cross-walk with Buildroot toolchain

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, crosswalk, buildroot

I want know how to add crosswalk to Buildroot or how can I cross-compile it with buildroot toolchain.

Answer (score 2):

Crosswalk is no longer maintained/developed: https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/crosswalk-final-release.html